# Populating a div with ajax, jquery function is not being called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a page with 2 buttons.
This page has this div:

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="display:none">
    <div id="subDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Clicking on a button populates the sub div with an ajax call and slides down the parent div.
The ajax calls a page that has a form in it and that calls a javascript file. The form is being populated with different values for each button.

In the javascript file that the form loads I have this code:

```
$(function() {
    alert('in');

    $('#close').on('click', function() {
       $('#subDiv').empty();
       $('#parentDiv').slideUp();
    });
});
```

The problem is, clicking on button 1 I get the alert, then I close the form and click on the second button, then I don't get the alert again.

Why is that?

Comment: What is your second button for?

Comment: provide code for the parentDiv click event that triggerd the ajax

Comment: from what i can tell te parentDiv click want trigger the ajax again

Comment: can you provide a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Your alert triggers on initialization (init) for the file. You don't have a `alert();` in the code of your close button.

If you like for your close button to trigger an `alert();` then you have to explicitly add it in the code. I changed the `alert()` to `console.log()` instead (better for debuging). If there is suppose to be alert you can change it. Does this make sense?

**EDIT**

The reason your button does not work is because you are loading the file dynamicly. You need to bind the event to ie `document`, `body` or some element that is in the DOM at load in your case, I do recommend `body` or `document`

```
$(function() {
    console.log('file init');

    $(document).on('click', '#close', function() {
       $('#subDiv').empty();
       $('#parentDiv').slideUp();

       console.log('I closed the form');
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't want the alert to be on the close button, I wanted to check that the jquery code is being called again when clicking the second button.

I moved the whole jquery code to the parent page and everything works fine now.

Comment: Well, that was what I was doing, putting a `console.log()` is a way for you to verify that your functions are triggered (debuging). It will write a message in the devtools console. @SigalZahavi

Comment: Thank you @Dejan, but it doesn't matter console or alert, I wanted to know why it's not being called not if it's being called or not.